# Таймер на фоне сервера

Tags: ajax, php, веб-сервер, mysql

Как создать таймер в php на фоне сервера для каждого пользователя?

---

По клику, сервер записывает в БД **конечную дату** в секундах:

```
$end = time() + 3600;
```

После этого нужно произвести старт таймера этому пользователю.

---

Запрос оставшегося времени:

```
$sec = time();

$time = $end - $sec;
```

По окончанию таймера, без участия пользователя нужно выполнить любой скрипт **{...}**

После падения и возобновления сервера, таймера всех пользователей должны запуститься вновь.

Без использования CRON, БЕЗ Linux

Comment: @Doofy, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Sergiks, не получилось создать таймер конкретному пользователю, я просто не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: каким макаром ты запустишь таймер после падение сервера ? :D

Comment: @Sergiks, это небыло вопросом учебного задания, это был мой личный интерес :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускать команды в опр. время можно командой [`at`](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/admin/manage-planned-tasks-on-linux-with-the-command-at.html) — т.е. я бы не полагался на БД и `php` а по событию назначал команды этой командой при клике. Напр. запускал в нужное время скрипт `php` с параметром `id` пользователя. Тогда и падение сервера не страшно.

---

Вы обновили вопрос, указав, что и на Linux расчитывать нельзя. Тогда есть еще решение, но, вангую, вы с ним не справитесь.

MySQL имеет собственный функционал для выполнения команд в заданное время: [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html). Примерно так можно создать событие:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO ... тут идёт процедура, которая выполнится через час.
```

Обычно там ставится любое SQL выражение. Но нам нужно выполнить внешнюю команду. Для этого понадобится расширить функционал MySQL [пользовательской функцией](http://www.mysqludf.org/) `sys_exec()` из пакета "Sys".

Comment: Я не понимаю, это сторонний софт для Linux?
В той статье толком не написано как это использовать, просто статья с набором команд и логами.

Допустим, запишу я в БД кол-во секунд (3600) с параметром id пользователя.
Как мне сделать, чтобы при конечном времени (через эти 3600 сек) выполнился скрипт, с параметром этого пользователя?

Comment: @Doofy, база тут абсолютно ни при чем. Вам нужно сформировать команду `at` (ее текст) с нужным временем и запустить ее.

Естественно, демон atd должен быть запущен при загрузке системы.

Comment: @Doofy, извините, не заметил, что Вы написали в вопросе "Без использования CRON, БЕЗ Linux".

--

Конечно, этот комментарий относится к Linux.

Comment: @Doofy команда `at` это стандартная часть многих дистрибутивов Linux. Дополнил ответ вариантом с MySQL.

Comment: @Sergiks, благодарю, это решение моей задачи:

    mysql_query("
    
    CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE
    AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 SECOND
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
    UPDATE data.users SET value = value + 1 WHERE users.id = 1
    
    ");

НО после выполнения задачи, снова запустить его нельзя.

`DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] myevent` - не помогает

P.S. параметр EVERY в моём случае не подходит.

Comment: Если решений не найду, то придётся генерировать имя события

    id_user & id_event